# selenium python - unable scroll ajax infinite page

Tags: python, selenium

I was able to scroll a regular page use below code, but unable to scroll simple ajax infinite page like http://darsa.in/sly/examples/infinite.html

Any idea?

---

### Working

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://play.google.com/store')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,10000);")
```

### Not Working

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://darsa.in/sly/examples/infinite.html')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,10000);")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set a page load time out before start scrolling. This will allow you to wait for 30s while page is not done with loading

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://darsa.in/sly/examples/infinite.html')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,10000);")
```

Comment: Just tried, that doesn't work. The page doesn't scroll at all.

Comment: try using driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"). http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/faq.html#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page will give you more information how all the methods work

Comment: no luck, i will look into the link you provided. thanks anyway.